# Passing custom claims to SP with Shibboleth Samltest.id

Tags: node.js, authentication, single-sign-on, saml, shibboleth

I am currently working on SAML-based SSO (Single Sign On) and using IDP (Identity Provider) provided by [samltest.id](https://samltest.id) (they are using Shibboleth) to test my NodeJS SP (Service Provider).
Samltest.id has a "Don't remember login" preference on its [login page](https://samltest.id/idp/profile/SAML2/Unsolicited/SSO?execution=e1s1). See the screenshot below:

[image]

How can I receive this preference/custom claim in my Service Provider application which uses `passport-saml` library?

As far as I understand it should be either provided in SAML response to my authentication request by samltest.id IDP (and reside somewhere inside of the `profile` object) or there should be some other means for retrieving this preference/claim. Once I get this claim, I will be able to create a new `SamlStrategy` object providing a `forceAuthn: true` property to make IDP reauthenticate the user even if they posses a valid session (essentially performing "don't remember login" functionality). However, I cannot find any custom claims in the SAML response object and I couldn't find this documented anywhere.

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S.
My auth code looks like the following:

```js
const samlStrategy = new SamlStrategy(
            {
                passReqToCallback: true,
                disableRequestedAuthnContext: true,
                callbackUrl: `${config.saml.hostUrl}${config.saml.replyPath}`,
                entryPoint: config.saml.entryPoint,
                logoutUrl: config.saml.logoutUrl,
                issuer: config.saml.issuer,
                cert: idpSigningCertString,
                authnContext: ["urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport"],
                signatureAlgorithm: 'sha256',
                decryptionPvk: spEncryptionKey || undefined,
                privateKey: spSigningKey || undefined,
                logoutRequestBinding: 'HTTP-Redirect',
                logoutCallbackUrl: `${config.saml.hostUrl}/logout/callback`
            },
            function(request, profile, done) {
                const user = {
                    ...profile, 
                    mail: profile['nameID']
                };

                const username = user.mail;
                findUserByUsername(username, function (error, dbUser) { // callback which is called in the end of findUserByUsername function
                    if (error) {
                        done(error);
                    } else if (!dbUser) {
                        done(new Error('No user found'));
                    }

                    if (error || !dbUser) { // destroy local session if error or user not found (currently not necessary)
                        request.logout(function (error) {
                            if (error) {
                                console.error(`Exception doing local logout: ${error}`);
                            }
                        });
                        return;
                    }

                    done(null, {...user, ...dbUser});
                });
            }
        );
```